# How do I filter using only a part of a variable?

Tags: r

I ran into a little bit of trouble while trying to cut down my data. The problem I'm having is that my dataset has the dates; however, the dates are listed as "2013-01-01" for example. I am trying to filter the data so that I only have data from 2014 and 2015. Is there anyway I can just filter only the year while ignoring the month and day? If you have any suggestions please let me know.

I tried using a for loop function to make all combinations of month date and year for 2014 and 2015, but that ended up backfiring because the output has extra spaces in between the dashes which makes it impossible to use to filter.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 2):

Try

```r
library(lubridate)
library(dplyr)

filter(dataset, between(year(the_date_column), 2014, 2015))
```

here we assume that `dataset` is a `data.frame` object and we are filtering rows based on the date column `the_date_column`.

The core of the answer is the function `year` from `lubridate` package. E.g.,

```
year('2014-01-06')
[1] 2014
```